# Change size of UITableView based on number of rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Currently I'm using a tableView to retrieve the data from the search function. So right now I wanted the tableView to shrink based on how many data that we get.

**So this is when the result is many, and it filled up the tableView:**

[image]

**And this is when the result we get only two.**

[image]

So I have use

```
 tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

and managed to hide the insets but not the size of the tableView. Is it possible to actually shrink down the size of the tableView based on number of cells that are loaded with data?

Comment: You don't wanna do that. If there's a blank space because of the returned data is not enough to fill your screen, let it be. Try to inspect the apps made by Apple, for example in Settings app, search for 1 item and you'll see there's a space too!

Comment: I actually wanted to shrink it because I have a webView behind the tableView to show the details of the result. So when I get the result and shown on the tableViewCell, and I have the webView to show the selected result. So if this way isn't practical what should I change in order to make it work? Sry I am trying to learn by practising.

Comment: You can dismiss the search screen or push a new screen to show the webView you've mentioned when the user taps on one search result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than constantly updating the size of your table view it would likely be easier to to have the background of the table view set to `.clear` and set the background color of the cells to gray. If you want touches to pass through to the underlying view where the table view is transparent, you can subclass `UITableView` and override `point(inside:,with:)` Like:

```
class TransparentTableView: UITableView {
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return self.indexPathForRow(at: point) != nil
    }
}
```

This causes touch event to register as being inside the table view if a cell is at that location, effectively changing the size of your table view to the locations occupied by cells.

Then in your storyboard or xib change the class of your `UITableView` to your subclass (`TransparentTableView` in my example).

#### Update

`point(inside:,with:)` determines whether a touch event should be considered "inside", and thus handled by a view. And by default will map to the bounds of the view. However, for us, we don't want to handle all touch events inside our table view bounds only those at locations where cells are present. To check if a cell is at a specific location we can call `indexPathForRow(at:)` if it returns an index path we know there's a cell there if it returns `nil` we know there's not one. So, we'll consider a point inside whenever  `self.indexPathForRow(at: point) != nil`

Comment: Thx for the reply, beyowulf! Somehow this solution works with my project nicely and it helps when I put the footerView code together. Just that I was a little bit confuse with the code. What does the code do?

Comment: I updated my answer. Hopefully that will help clear things up.